# Getting invalid error for Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'

Tags: json

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "template.openshift.io/v1",
    "kind": "Template",
    "labels": {
        "app": "${NAME}",
        "template": "jenkins-persistent-monitored"
    },
    "message": "A Jenkins service (monitored via Prometheus) has been created in your project.  Log into Jenkins with your OpenShift account.  The tutorial at https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/jenkins/README.md contains more information about using this template.",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "description": "Jenkins service, with persistent storage. \n\n To run this template extra RBAC permissions need to be provideed to the use to be able to create the ServiceMonitor Custom Resource managed by the prometheus-operator. \n\nNOTE: You must have persistent volumes available in your cluster to use this template.",
            "iconClass": "icon-jenkins",
            "openshift.io/display-name": "Jenkins Monitored",
            "openshift.io/documentation-url": "https://docs.okd.io/latest/using_images/other_images/jenkins.html",
            "openshift.io/long-description": "This template deploys a Jenkins server capable of managing OpenShift Pipeline builds and supporting OpenShift-based oauth login and Prometheus monitoring. DISCLAIMER: User needs to have RBAC Permissions to create the Service Monitor.",
            "openshift.io/provider-display-name": "Red Hat, Inc.",
            "openshift.io/support-url": "https://access.redhat.com",
            "samples.operator.openshift.io/version": "4.9.52",
            "tags": "instant-app,jenkins"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-06-30T13:15:03Z",
        "labels": {
            "samples.operator.openshift.io/managed": "true"
        },
        "name": "jenkins-persistent-monitored",
        "namespace": "openshift",
        "resourceVersion": "413789853",
        "uid": "2135b7ab-e42a-41a0-a45e-be37b752e99a"
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Route",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout": "4m",
                    "template.openshift.io/expose-uri": "http://{.spec.host}{.spec.path}"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "tls": {
                    "insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy": "Redirect",
                    "termination": "edge"
                },
                "to": {
                    "kind": "Service",
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "accessModes": [
                    "ReadWriteOnce"
                ],
                "resources": {
                    "requests": {
                        "storage": "${VOLUME_CAPACITY}"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "config.openshift.io/inject-trusted-cabundle": "true"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-trusted-ca-bundle"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "template.alpha.openshift.io/wait-for-ready": "true"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "replicas": 1,
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "strategy": {
                    "type": "Recreate"
                },
                "template": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "labels": {
                            "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                        }
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "capabilities": {},
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH",
                                        "value": "${ENABLE_OAUTH}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_REDIRECT_PROMPT",
                                        "value": "true"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "DISABLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_MONITORS",
                                        "value": "${DISABLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_MONITORS}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "KUBERNETES_MASTER",
                                        "value": "https://kubernetes.default:443"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "KUBERNETES_TRUST_CERTIFICATES",
                                        "value": "true"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME",
                                        "value": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "JNLP_SERVICE_NAME",
                                        "value": "${JNLP_SERVICE_NAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "ENABLE_FATAL_ERROR_LOG_FILE",
                                        "value": "${ENABLE_FATAL_ERROR_LOG_FILE}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "JENKINS_UC_INSECURE",
                                        "value": "${JENKINS_UC_INSECURE}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG",
                                        "value": "/var/lib/jenkins/proxy.yaml"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image": " ",
                                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                                "livenessProbe": {
                                    "failureThreshold": 2,
                                    "httpGet": {
                                        "path": "/login",
                                        "port": 8080
                                    },
                                    "initialDelaySeconds": 420,
                                    "periodSeconds": 360,
                                    "timeoutSeconds": 240
                                },
                                "name": "jenkins",
                                "readinessProbe": {
                                    "httpGet": {
                                        "path": "/login",
                                        "port": 8080
                                    },
                                    "initialDelaySeconds": 3,
                                    "timeoutSeconds": 240
                                },
                                "resources": {
                                    "limits": {
                                        "memory": "${MEMORY_LIMIT}"
                                    }
                                },
                                "securityContext": {
                                    "capabilities": {},
                                    "privileged": false
                                },
                                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                                "volumeMounts": [
                                    {
                                        "mountPath": "/var/lib/jenkins",
                                        "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-data"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "mountPath": "/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors",
                                        "name": "all-ca-certs"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                        "restartPolicy": "Always",
                        "serviceAccountName": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}",
                        "volumes": [
                            {
                                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-data",
                                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                                    "claimName": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "all-ca-certs",
                                "projected": {
                                    "sources": [
                                        {
                                            {
                                                "configMap": {
                                                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-trusted-ca-bundle",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                                            "path": "global-ca-bundle.crt"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "configMap": {
                                                    "name": "oauth-serving-cert",
                                                    "items": [
                                                        {
                                                            "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                                            "path": "oauth-ca-bundle.crt"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                            ],
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "imageChangeParams": {
                            "automatic": true,
                            "containerNames": [
                                "jenkins"
                            ],
                            "from": {
                                "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                                "name": "${JENKINS_IMAGE_STREAM_TAG}",
                                "namespace": "${NAMESPACE}"
                            },
                            "lastTriggeredImage": ""
                        },
                        "type": "ImageChange"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ConfigChange"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "ServiceAccount",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.jenkins": "{\"kind\":\"OAuthRedirectReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"Route\",\"name\":\"${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}\"}}"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "groupNames": null,
            "kind": "RoleBinding",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}_edit"
            },
            "roleRef": {
                "name": "edit"
            },
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "kind": "ServiceAccount",
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Service",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${JNLP_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "name": "agent",
                        "nodePort": 0,
                        "port": 50000,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "targetPort": 50000
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "sessionAffinity": "None",
                "type": "ClusterIP"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Service",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "service.alpha.openshift.io/dependencies": "[{\"name\": \"${JNLP_SERVICE_NAME}\", \"namespace\": \"\", \"kind\": \"Service\"}]",
                    "service.openshift.io/infrastructure": "true"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "name": "web",
                        "nodePort": 0,
                        "port": 80,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "targetPort": 8080
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "sessionAffinity": "None",
                "type": "ClusterIP"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "monitoring.coreos.com/v1",
            "kind": "ServiceMonitor",
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${NAME}",
                    "name": "jenkins"
                },
                "name": "${NAME}-monitored"
            },
            "spec": {
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "interval": "10s",
                        "path": "/prometheus/",
                        "port": "web"
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "matchLabels": {
                        "app": "${NAME}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [
        {
            "description": "Name of the Jenkins instance to be monitored defined by the `app` label",
            "displayName": "Name",
            "name": "NAME",
            "required": true,
            "value": "jenkins-persistent"
        },
        {
            "description": "The name of the OpenShift Service exposed for the Jenkins container.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins Service Name",
            "name": "JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME",
            "value": "jenkins"
        },
        {
            "description": "The name of the service used for master/slave communication.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins JNLP Service Name",
            "name": "JNLP_SERVICE_NAME",
            "value": "jenkins-jnlp"
        },
        {
            "description": "Whether to enable OAuth OpenShift integration. If false, the static account 'admin' will be initialized with the password 'password'.",
            "displayName": "Enable OAuth in Jenkins",
            "name": "ENABLE_OAUTH",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "description": "Maximum amount of memory the container can use.",
            "displayName": "Memory Limit",
            "name": "MEMORY_LIMIT",
            "value": "1Gi"
        },
        {
            "description": "Volume space available for data, e.g. 512Mi, 2Gi.",
            "displayName": "Volume Capacity",
            "name": "VOLUME_CAPACITY",
            "required": true,
            "value": "1Gi"
        },
        {
            "description": "The OpenShift Namespace where the Jenkins ImageStream resides.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins ImageStream Namespace",
            "name": "NAMESPACE",
            "value": "openshift"
        },
        {
            "description": "Whether to perform memory intensive, possibly slow, synchronization with the Jenkins Update Center on start.  If true, the Jenkins core update monitor and site warnings monitor are disabled.",
            "displayName": "Disable memory intensive administrative monitors",
            "name": "DISABLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_MONITORS",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "description": "Name of the ImageStreamTag to be used for the Jenkins image.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins ImageStreamTag",
            "name": "JENKINS_IMAGE_STREAM_TAG",
            "value": "jenkins:2"
        },
        {
            "description": "When a fatal error occurs, an error log is created with information and the state obtained at the time of the fatal error.",
            "displayName": "Fatal Error Log File",
            "name": "ENABLE_FATAL_ERROR_LOG_FILE",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "description": "Whether to allow use of a Jenkins Update Center that uses invalid certificate (self-signed, unknown CA). If any value other than 'false', certificate check is bypassed. By default, certificate check is enforced.",
            "displayName": "Allows use of Jenkins Update Center repository with invalid SSL certificate",
            "name": "JENKINS_UC_INSECURE",
            "value": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: First off:
Just putting the only context with the question in the headline is not very nice....

Second, this unformatted mess is really bad to read. The least that would have been useful would have been a formatting, so that one can read it to some extent.

Comment: I tried adding this as code, but it's asking me to fix the format, I believe it could be due to invalidity :(

Comment: There you go. Formatted.

Comment: Thanks a ton :) @phuzi could you please guide me in knowing the issue?

Comment: Where did you get the JSON from? Did you build it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

this is a fixed version, but I don't think that it is a good idea to fix it manually, you have to fix the code that created this json

```
{
    "apiVersion": "template.openshift.io/v1",
    "kind": "Template",
    "labels": {
        "app": "${NAME}",
        "template": "jenkins-persistent-monitored"
    },
    "message": "A Jenkins service (monitored via Prometheus) has been created in your project.  Log into Jenkins with your OpenShift account.  The tutorial at https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/jenkins/README.md contains more information about using this template.",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "description": "Jenkins service, with persistent storage. \n\n To run this template extra RBAC permissions need to be provideed to the use to be able to create the ServiceMonitor Custom Resource managed by the prometheus-operator. \n\nNOTE: You must have persistent volumes available in your cluster to use this template.",
            "iconClass": "icon-jenkins",
            "openshift.io/display-name": "Jenkins Monitored",
            "openshift.io/documentation-url": "https://docs.okd.io/latest/using_images/other_images/jenkins.html",
            "openshift.io/long-description": "This template deploys a Jenkins server capable of managing OpenShift Pipeline builds and supporting OpenShift-based oauth login and Prometheus monitoring. DISCLAIMER: User needs to have RBAC Permissions to create the Service Monitor.",
            "openshift.io/provider-display-name": "Red Hat, Inc.",
            "openshift.io/support-url": "https://access.redhat.com",
            "samples.operator.openshift.io/version": "4.9.52",
            "tags": "instant-app,jenkins"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-06-30T13:15:03Z",
        "labels": {
            "samples.operator.openshift.io/managed": "true"
        },
        "name": "jenkins-persistent-monitored",
        "namespace": "openshift",
        "resourceVersion": "413789853",
        "uid": "2135b7ab-e42a-41a0-a45e-be37b752e99a"
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Route",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout": "4m",
                    "template.openshift.io/expose-uri": "http://{.spec.host}{.spec.path}"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "tls": {
                    "insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy": "Redirect",
                    "termination": "edge"
                },
                "to": {
                    "kind": "Service",
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "accessModes": [
                    "ReadWriteOnce"
                ],
                "resources": {
                    "requests": {
                        "storage": "${VOLUME_CAPACITY}"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "ConfigMap",
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "config.openshift.io/inject-trusted-cabundle": "true"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-trusted-ca-bundle"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "RoleBinding",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}_edit"
            },
            "spec": {
                "replicas": 1,
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "strategy": {
                    "type": "Recreate"
                },
                "template": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "labels": {
                            "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                        }
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "capabilities": {},
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_OAUTH",
                                        "value": "${ENABLE_OAUTH}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "OPENSHIFT_ENABLE_REDIRECT_PROMPT",
                                        "value": "true"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "DISABLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_MONITORS",
                                        "value": "${DISABLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_MONITORS}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "KUBERNETES_MASTER",
                                        "value": "https://kubernetes.default:443"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "KUBERNETES_TRUST_CERTIFICATES",
                                        "value": "true"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME",
                                        "value": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "JNLP_SERVICE_NAME",
                                        "value": "${JNLP_SERVICE_NAME}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "ENABLE_FATAL_ERROR_LOG_FILE",
                                        "value": "${ENABLE_FATAL_ERROR_LOG_FILE}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "JENKINS_UC_INSECURE",
                                        "value": "${JENKINS_UC_INSECURE}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG",
                                        "value": "/var/lib/jenkins/proxy.yaml"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image": " ",
                                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                                "livenessProbe": {
                                    "failureThreshold": 2,
                                    "httpGet": {
                                        "path": "/login",
                                        "port": 8080
                                    },
                                    "initialDelaySeconds": 420,
                                    "periodSeconds": 360,
                                    "timeoutSeconds": 240
                                },
                                "name": "jenkins",
                                "readinessProbe": {
                                    "httpGet": {
                                        "path": "/login",
                                        "port": 8080
                                    },
                                    "initialDelaySeconds": 3,
                                    "timeoutSeconds": 240
                                },
                                "resources": {
                                    "limits": {
                                        "memory": "${MEMORY_LIMIT}"
                                    }
                                },
                                "securityContext": {
                                    "capabilities": {},
                                    "privileged": false
                                },
                                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                                "volumeMounts": [
                                    {
                                        "mountPath": "/var/lib/jenkins",
                                        "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-data"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "mountPath": "/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors",
                                        "name": "all-ca-certs"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                        "restartPolicy": "Always",
                        "serviceAccountName": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}",
                        "volumes": [
                            {
                                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-data",
                                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                                    "claimName": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "all-ca-certs",
                                "projected": {
                                    "sources": [
                                        {
                                            "configMap": {
                                                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-trusted-ca-bundle",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                                        "path": "global-ca-bundle.crt"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "configMap": {
                                                "name": "oauth-serving-cert",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                                        "path": "oauth-ca-bundle.crt"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "triggers": [
                            {
                                "imageChangeParams": {
                                    "automatic": true,
                                    "containerNames": [
                                        "jenkins"
                                    ],
                                    "from": {
                                        "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                                        "name": "${JENKINS_IMAGE_STREAM_TAG}",
                                        "namespace": "${NAMESPACE}"
                                    },
                                    "lastTriggeredImage": ""
                                },
                                "type": "ImageChange"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "ConfigChange"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "ServiceAccount",
                "metadata": {
                    "annotations": {
                        "serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.jenkins": "{\"kind\":\"OAuthRedirectReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"Route\",\"name\":\"${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}\"}}"
                    },
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                }
            },
            "groupNames": null,
            "roleRef": {
                "name": "edit"
            },
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "kind": "ServiceAccount",
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Service",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${JNLP_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "name": "agent",
                        "nodePort": 0,
                        "port": 50000,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "targetPort": 50000
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "sessionAffinity": "None",
                "type": "ClusterIP"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Service",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "service.alpha.openshift.io/dependencies": "[{\"name\": \"${JNLP_SERVICE_NAME}\", \"namespace\": \"\", \"kind\": \"Service\"}]",
                    "service.openshift.io/infrastructure": "true"
                },
                "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "name": "web",
                        "nodePort": 0,
                        "port": 80,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "targetPort": 8080
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "sessionAffinity": "None",
                "type": "ClusterIP"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "monitoring.coreos.com/v1",
            "kind": "ServiceMonitor",
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "app": "${NAME}",
                    "name": "jenkins"
                },
                "name": "${NAME}-monitored"
            },
            "spec": {
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "interval": "10s",
                        "path": "/prometheus/",
                        "port": "web"
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "matchLabels": {
                        "app": "${NAME}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [
        {
            "description": "Name of the Jenkins instance to be monitored defined by the `app` label",
            "displayName": "Name",
            "name": "NAME",
            "required": true,
            "value": "jenkins-persistent"
        },
        {
            "description": "The name of the OpenShift Service exposed for the Jenkins container.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins Service Name",
            "name": "JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME",
            "value": "jenkins"
        },
        {
            "description": "The name of the service used for master/slave communication.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins JNLP Service Name",
            "name": "JNLP_SERVICE_NAME",
            "value": "jenkins-jnlp"
        },
        {
            "description": "Whether to enable OAuth OpenShift integration. If false, the static account 'admin' will be initialized with the password 'password'.",
            "displayName": "Enable OAuth in Jenkins",
            "name": "ENABLE_OAUTH",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "description": "Maximum amount of memory the container can use.",
            "displayName": "Memory Limit",
            "name": "MEMORY_LIMIT",
            "value": "1Gi"
        },
        {
            "description": "Volume space available for data, e.g. 512Mi, 2Gi.",
            "displayName": "Volume Capacity",
            "name": "VOLUME_CAPACITY",
            "required": true,
            "value": "1Gi"
        },
        {
            "description": "The OpenShift Namespace where the Jenkins ImageStream resides.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins ImageStream Namespace",
            "name": "NAMESPACE",
            "value": "openshift"
        },
        {
            "description": "Whether to perform memory intensive, possibly slow, synchronization with the Jenkins Update Center on start.  If true, the Jenkins core update monitor and site warnings monitor are disabled.",
            "displayName": "Disable memory intensive administrative monitors",
            "name": "DISABLE_ADMINISTRATIVE_MONITORS",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "description": "Name of the ImageStreamTag to be used for the Jenkins image.",
            "displayName": "Jenkins ImageStreamTag",
            "name": "JENKINS_IMAGE_STREAM_TAG",
            "value": "jenkins:2"
        },
        {
            "description": "When a fatal error occurs, an error log is created with information and the state obtained at the time of the fatal error.",
            "displayName": "Fatal Error Log File",
            "name": "ENABLE_FATAL_ERROR_LOG_FILE",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "description": "Whether to allow use of a Jenkins Update Center that uses invalid certificate (self-signed, unknown CA). If any value other than 'false', certificate check is bypassed. By default, certificate check is enforced.",
            "displayName": "Allows use of Jenkins Update Center repository with invalid SSL certificate",
            "name": "JENKINS_UC_INSECURE",
            "value": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to work with above particular section, but it failed, I have pasted entire content here, please help with this .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is this bit:

```json
{
    "name": "all-ca-certs",
    "projected": {
        "sources": [
            {
                {
                    "configMap": {
                        "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-trusted-ca-bundle",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                "path": "global-ca-bundle.crt"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "configMap": {
                        "name": "oauth-serving-cert",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                "path": "oauth-ca-bundle.crt"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In particular the extra set of opening braces around the contents of the sources array:

```json
        "sources": [
            {
                { ... },
                { ... }
            }
        ]
```

This is invalid!

There are other issues here though.

Comment: Thank you, got to the know problem.

Answer (score -1):

So this is the broken part:

```
    {
    "name": "all-ca-certs",
    "projected": {
        "sources": [
            {
                {
                    "configMap": {
                        "name": "${JENKINS_SERVICE_NAME}-trusted-ca-bundle",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                "path": "global-ca-bundle.crt"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "configMap": {
                        "name": "oauth-serving-cert",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "key": "ca-bundle.crt",
                                "path": "oauth-ca-bundle.crt"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You are having a second opening curly bracket in line 6, you should have a name there, which shoul be a "string".
In JSON, an opening curly bracket ({) must be followed by a name, followed by a colon (:), followed by a value. It is not allowed to write two opening curly braces directly after each other without having a name or value between them.

Comment: So after you posted a complete and properly formatted version of the .json this is still valid - its the duplicate opening curly braces after "sources" . You have to remove one of them as wlell as an corresponding closing bracket.